# What is the replacement of Ingres10Dialect in Hibernate 6?

Tags: hibernate, hibernate-6.x

When upgrade to hibernate 6, the Ingres10Dialect class is not found.

I have some legacy application, which worked in Hibernate 5.4.20.
Is there any replacement for that in hibernate 6?

FQN: org.hibernate.dialect.Ingres10Dialect

Comment: `org.hibernate.community.dialect.Ingres10Dialect` is located in [hibernate-community-dialects](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.hibernate.orm/hibernate-community-dialects)

Comment: Great, this worked! Thanks @AndreyB.Panfilov